# How to define a command if the function needs to take an argument from the script itself?

Tags: command

Suppose I am defining a few commands that are similar in functionality. In this particular case, I am defining a few commands that each echoes a particular message:

```
function! EchoMessage(text)
    echom text
endfunction

let thousand_chars = "天地玄黃，宇宙洪荒。日月盈昃，辰宿列張。 寒來暑往，秋收冬藏。閏餘成歲，律呂調陽 ..."
let lorem_ipsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, ..."
let brown_fox = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."

command! ThousandCharacters call EchoMessage(thousand_chars)
command! LoremIpsum call EchoMessage(lorem_ipsum)
command! BrownFox call EchoMessage(brown_fox)
```

I have written it in this way to be able to reuse `EchoMessage` for many commands. Unfortunately, an error is produced when any of the commands (e.g. `:LoremIpsum`) are called, because vim will not provide `text` when `EchoMessage` is called using a command.

How can I structure my code so that the commands can make use of a common function (e.g. `EchoMessage`) with one argument provided in the script itself (e.g. `brown_fox`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that, in the body of your `EchoMessage()` function, `text` does not refer to the value passed in, but instead to a different local variable. Use `a:` to refer to parameters passed in:

```
echom a:text
```

See [`:help internal-variables`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#internal-variables) (and specifically [`:help function-argument`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#function-argument)) for more details.